# php fill string with special characters

Tags: php, string, foreach, fill

I wrote this:

```
$date = $_SESSION['basket']['date'];
$number = $_SESSION['basket']['number'];
$type = $_SESSION['basket']['type'];

if ($number > 9) {
    $fill = "********";
} else {
    $fill = "*********";
}

echo "<pre>Date         | Number   | Type |</pre>";

foreach ($date as $key => $value) {
    echo "<pre>" . $date[$key] . " | " . $number[$key] . $fill . "| " . $type[$key] .  "</pre>";
}
```

$number is always a value between 1 and 14 (number of days), ie one or two characters. The goal is to have a nice alignment in my output. Here is the result of my output:

```
Date         | Number   | Type
28.02.2017   | 2********| Top
26.02.2017   | 11********| Basic
```

This is not working, the value of $fill is always the same, the else option of my if seems not to be recognized. Any idea how to solve this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be using [`str_pad` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$targetLenght = 12;
$string ='Text';

$string = str_pad($string ,  $targetLenght, '*');
echo $string;
```

results in:
    Text********

Comment: the right str_pad usage for this problem context :)

Answer (score 0):

`if - else` statement was constructed incorrectly.
Use the following:

```
if ($number > 9) {
    $fill = "********";
} else {
    $fill = "*********";
}
```

---

Or even shorter by using [***str_pad***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function:

```
...
$number = str_pad($number, 9, '*', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your ending bracket of your else statement is in wrong position. Shouldn't your if else block look something like this?:

```
if ($number > 9)     {
    $fill = "********";
} else  {
    $fill = "*********";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function:

$number = str_pad($number, 9, '*', STR_PAD_RIGHT);

How it works ir your situation:

```
function padNumber($number) 
{
  return str_pad($number, 9, '*', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
}

foreach ($date as $key => $value) 
{
  echo sprintf("<pre>%s|%s|%s</pre>", $date[$key], padNumber($number[$key]), $type[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($number > 9)
```

It semes to me that $number is an array not?? so you need to write something like this :

```
if( $number[$index] > 9 )
```

This is an ameliored code check it .

```
$date = $_SESSION['basket']['date'];
$number = $_SESSION['basket']['number'];
$type = $_SESSION['basket']['type']; 

echo "<pre>Date         | Number   | Type |</pre>";

foreach ($date as $key => $value){
if ($number[$key] > 9)     {
   $fill = "********";
 }else $fill = "*********"; {
}
echo "<pre>$date[$key] . " | " . $number[$key] . $fill . "| " .$type[$key]."</pre>";      
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Kark92, your solution is fine for me. It's works.